# OpenID. How create special link

Tags: image, authentication, hyperlink, openid, registration

I'm trying to make OpenID authentication on the site, but I do not form, and links. 
Example: [there](https://signin.rpxnow.com/openid/embed?token_url=https%3A%2F%2Frpxnow.com%2Ffinish%3Fdest%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Frpxnow.com%252Frelying_parties%252Fcreate&language_preference=en) But a question .. how do I make such links for services such as google, yahoo, aol, twitter, facebook and others? Understand?)
Sorry for bad english..

Comment: maybe with english you'll get more fare :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What those links do is submit a predefined value to the OpenID process, usually the OP Identifier for that site.  You should be able to use something like [Open Selector](http://open-selector.com/); if not directly, by looking at it's source code.

Comment: This is not completely true.  Facebook and Twitter for instance are not Open ID providers.

Answer (score 1):

**[Here's](http://jvance.com/pages/JQueryOpenIDPlugin.xhtml)** a cool open ID selector that will do the job of redirecting to the required provider upon clicking the icons, just have a look at the page and you will know what I am trying to say.